# Selecting unique combination from text column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two columns in my dataset, as below. What I want is to select only one combination out of all 'like' combinations. For this case, (orange,fruit) and (fruit,orange) are equivalent, so I need only one of these. Plus, now that fruit has been mapped to orange, I don't need anything for fruit anymore. So basically (fruit,red) would become (orange,red)

```
C1      C2
orange  fruit
orange  color
orange  apple
apple   red
apple   fruit
fruit   red
fruit   apple
fruit   mango
fruit   orange
```

This is the code I tried in Python

```
# Convert data frame to set of tuples

l = []

for i,x in df.iterrows():
    l.append((x['C1'],x['C2']))

s_comb = set(l)

# Set of unique values from C1
s = set(list(df['C1']))

#Initialize x with first element of s
x = list(df['C1'])[0]
x=[x]

# Code for creating combinations

for i in s:
    if i not in x:
        for j in x:
            if (i,j) not in s_comb:
                x.append(i)
```

Expected Output:

```
C1      C2
orange  fruit
orange  color
orange  apple
orange  red
orange  mango
```

Currently the code is taking very long, and I'm not sure about the accuracy of the code output.

Comment: One simple way to do this would be to sort along the row axis with `sort_values()` [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then use `drop_duplicates()` [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to get rid of repeat value.

Comment: So you want to replace every occurrence of Fruit with orange and then check for unique combinations? It's hard to understand how you're creating the mapping and checking uniqueness

Comment: @RobertDerber please read the expected output, it is a little more complicated than dropping duplicates

Answer (score 4):

For the first part of the question, you can do this:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: (str(set(x[['C1', 'C2']]))), axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='C')[['C1', 'C2']]
```

For the second part, you can do something similar:

```
df['Cmin'] = df.apply(lambda x: min(x[['C1', 'C2']]), axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Cmin')[['C1', 'C2']] 

df['Cmax'] = df.apply(lambda x: max(x[['C1', 'C2']]), axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Cmax')[['C1', 'C2']]
```

Comment: Thank you @foxpal, the first part is working perfectly. The second part is not giving the expected output but I I like the thought process which you have used. Kudos to the way you have approached the problem. Once again, Thank you Champ.

Comment: @Dr.Chuck, sorry I misinterpreted your second question. Hope you get to solve it. I think the difficulty of this problem arises from the mixed meaning between 'C1' and 'C2'. Ideally the table would be more ordered, with 'C1' being 'fruit' and 'C2' being 'color', or similar. I that case, what you wanted to do would be much easier.